# WebClient.DownloadString to work with 2 urls

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2
    Dim downloader As New WebClient
    downloader.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Dim mystring As String = downloader.DownloadString("ONE LINK HERE" And "OTHER LINK HERE")    

    Dim myregex As String = "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b:\d{2,5}"  
    Dim source As String = mystring  
    Dim findme As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(source, myregex)  
    For Each mymatch As Match In findme  
        ListBox1.Items.Add(mymatch)  
    Next
```

New here, sorry for bad formatation, all i want to do is download string from 2 urls at same time without errors

Comment: To format the code simply paste it, select all of it and then click on the _{}_ button or ctrl+k

Comment: One `WebClient` can perform one download at a time. If you want to perform multiple downloads then use multiple `WebClients`.